# php page working on localhost but not running on server

Tags: php, database

i created a website which is working in localhost but when i upload these pages to server, only php pages are showing blank, html pages are working fine **.
This is my php code in my page :-**

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once 'dbconnect.php';
if(isset($_SESSION['user'])!="")
{
    header("Location: home.php");
}
if(isset($_POST['btn-login']))
{
    $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
    $upass = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pass']);
    $res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email'");
    $row=mysql_fetch_array($res);
    if($row['password']==md5($upass))
    {
        $_SESSION['user'] = $row['user_id'];
        header("Location: home.php");
    }
    else
    {
        ?>
        <script>alert('wrong details');</script>
        <?php
    }
```

**and code for dbconnect.php**

```
<?php
if(!mysql_connect("localhost","root",""))
{
    die('oops connection problem ! --> '.mysql_error());
}
if(!mysql_select_db("member"))
{
    die('oops database selection problem ! --> '.mysql_error());
}
?>
```

Comment: the mysql_ extension has been deprecated for a while.

Comment: You should change to PDO or Mysqli and use prepared/parameterized queries to protect against SQL injection hacks. You should also change to use [PHPs built in password API](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php), MD5 is NOT recommended for storing passwords.

Comment: In order to solve issues like these you should check the error log on the server. A white page in PHP is generally a 500 internal server error, in production environments unhandled errors are set to just display a blank page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 improvement required:

1.Change all `mysql_*` function to `mysqli_*`
2. change `if(!mysql_select_db("member"))` to `if(!mysql_select_db($con , "member"))` as  this function receives 2 parameter one is `$con`  variable in which you have to store the connection of database i.e  `$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");`
hope this will helps you

Comment: why even mysqli its day is over , all new code should use PDO

Comment: @smith That is an opinion which isn't shared by all.  It's still a valid choice to use mysqli and it's up to you what you use.

Comment: by any objective standard PDO is superior, that's not an opinion

Answer (score 0):

It's probably an error of deprecation, if it was just the connexion, you would get atleast your error output on the page.

So try migrating to `mysqli` (mysql is deprecated so if your server is running on PHP7, it's just not accessible anymore).

And change :

```
if(!mysql_connect("localhost","root",""))
{
    die('oops connection problem ! --> '.mysql_error());
}
if(!mysql_select_db("member"))
{
    die('oops database selection problem ! --> '.mysql_error());
}
```

To :

```
if (!($db = mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password", "dbName")) {
    die('oops connection problem ! --> ' . mysqli_connect_error());
 }
```

Make sure you enter the right db information.

And replace each `mysql` method by its `mysqli` equivalent, you'll have to use that `$db` variable.

Comment: most servers use "localhost"

Comment: I know some that don't and I even use some of them. So it still can be the problem. I included all the information (username, pass, etc) that should be checked. Usually you don't have "root" as an username on a server that you don't own.

Comment: He gets a 500 internal server error (white page), if he was just unable to connect to the database then he should have gotten a white page with `oops connection problem ! --> etc`.

Comment: The code execution is set to die on a connection problem. But you might be right, I assume he is on shared hosting which means a localhost/root db login makes no sense

Comment: thank you guys,i used **mysqli** equivalent and **$db** variable in my both page... and this time its working :)